# Is there a way I can add rows of values to a dataframe in new columns, based on existing values in the dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, back-testing

I'm trying to backtest a trading strategy.

Columns that I already have saved as a dataframe:
'Date', 'A', 'B', 'C'

I am trying to create columns D, E, F, and G to the existing dataframe by performing operations row by row.

I'm trying to:

1. Start with a value of 1000 for D0.
2. Calculate E0 by D0 * C0.
3. Calculate F0 by E0 / A0.
4. Calculate G0 by (B0 * F0)-(A0 * F0)
5. Calculate D1 by D0 + G0
6. Repeat for each row.
   For example, E1 = (D1 * C1). F1 = E1 / A1 and so on.

| Date | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 200 | 0.05 | 1000 | 1000*0.05 | (1000*0.05)/100 | (B0 * F0)-(A0 * F0) |
| 1 | 200 | 150 | 0.01 | 1000 + (B0 * F0)-(A0 * F0) |  |  |  |
| 2 | 150 | 160 | 0.03 |  |  |  |  |

There are 500 rows in total and doing all these manually would obviously be impossible, which made me think I need to use for loop some how but I'm not sure how. How would I go about this?

```
df.at[0, 'D'] = 1000
for i in range(1, 500):
    df.at[i, 'D'] = df.at[i-1, 'D'] + df.at[i-1, 'G']
    df.at[i, 'E'] = df.at[i, 'D'] * df.at[i, 'C']
    df.at[i, 'F'] = df.at[i, 'E'] / df.at[i, 'A']
    df.at[i, 'G'] = (df.at[i, 'B'] - df.at[i, 'A']) * df.at[i, 'F']
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute an iterative operation on 500 rows, using an explicit for loop is the easiest solution.:

```
for i in range(1, n):
    df.at[i, "D"] = df.at[i-1, "D"]+df.at[i-1, "G"]
    df.at[i, "E"] = df.at[i, "D"]*df.at[i, "C"]
    df.at[i, "F"] = df.at[i, "E"]/df.at[i, "A"]
    df.at[i, "G"] = (df.at[i, "B"]-df.at[i, "A"])*df.at[i, "F"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. If I wanted to set an initial value as 1000 for column "D", would I have to declare it outside of the loop first as a variable?

Comment: Yes. Simply initialise the first row with `df.at[0, column_name]` before the loop.

Comment: Thank you again! Would you mind helping me solve one more problem? I have an existing column called 'trade_status' in the dataframe that tells me whether a trade is executed on the day (True/False value). I want D_i = D_i-1 + G_i-1 only when the column says true. Otherwise, I want D_i = D_i-1. Do I need to make an if-condition in the for loop?

Comment: Yes, do so. Don't hesitate to reach out if you have problems implementing the solution.